# How to manipulate string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a DateTime string like below:

```js
"11/20/2022 19.00"
```

I just want to delete the spaces until the end, how do I do that?

I'm expecting the below output:

```js
"11/20/2022"
```

Answer (score 1):

### If your date string follows the standard format

Try to use [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and pass the beginning and end of the slice portion as the first and second params.

```js
const dateTime = "11/20/2022 19.00"

console.log(dateTime.slice(0, 10))
```

### If your date string did not follow the standard format

You can first split it by space ([`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) and then use the first part of the output array generated by the `split` function.

```js
const dateTime = "1/2/2022 19.00"

console.log(dateTime.split(" ")[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can simply use split function of javascript**

You can use split function of javascript to split the string and then take first index as you required result.

```
let a = "11/20/2022 19.00";
let reqFormat = a.split(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If space comes break the `string`

```js
let str = "11/20/2022 19.00"
let ans=""; 
for(let i=0 ; i<str.length ; i++){
    if(str[i]!==" "){
      ans+=str[i];
    }
    else{
      break ;
    }
}
console.log((ans));
```